# Is there a way to get a report on the tests that fail most often in TFS build reports?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tfs, tfsbuild

Is there a way to get a report on the tests that fail most often in TFS build reports?

We want to identify which are the most common culprits from a range of tfs builds that have run over the past few weeks.

Answer (score 1):

Currently not. In Team Foundation Server 2015 SP 2 they have added an update for testing. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/11/18/test-results-in-build/.

But in the end they say the following:

> **What’s coming soon?**
>
> - This experience works great with the new build system (Build vNext). Support XAML Builds is coming soon.
> - Capability to view all test results, including passed tests, and option to filter test results by outcome.
> - And many more interesting features…

So I think with the capability to view all test results you will be able to do something like this.

For now, maybe a custom extension or a tool like PowerBi can help you.